# Closed form for $\prod_{k=1}^n \binom{k^2+2k}{k^2}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, closed-form, products

Does anybody know how I can find a closed form for the expression
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \binom{k^2+2k}{k^2}?
$$
There are many ways to handle such things, but with *sum* instead of *product*. Here, I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Sorry, stupid error. That's what I meant.

The first thing I would do is to semplify it: we have that

$\displaystyle\binom{r}{k} = \dfrac{r}{k}\binom{r-1}{k-1}$

so that you have

$\displaystyle \binom{k^2+2k}{k^2} = \prod_{j=0}^{k^2} \dfrac{k^2 + 2k - j}{k^2 - j} \binom{2k}{0} = \prod_{j=0}^{k^2} \dfrac{k^2 + 2k - j}{k^2 - j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $k$,
$$
\binom{k^2+2k}{k^2}=\frac{(k^2+2k)!}{(k^2)!\,(2k)!}=\frac{((k+1)^2)!}{(k^2)!}\,\frac1{(k+1)^2}\,\frac1{(2k)!},
$$
hence
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \binom{k^2+2k}{k^2}=((n+1)^2)!\,\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{k+1}\right)^2\,\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{(2k)!}\right)=\frac{((n+1)^2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{(2k)!}.
$$
This reduces the problem to finding a "closed form" for the product
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)!,
$$
a task which does not seem doable if "closed form" has one of its usual meanings.

Comment: That doesn't seem to me a closed form.

Comment: @AlessandroFlati Thanks for this most constructive comment.

Comment: $\displaystyle\prod_1^nk!=n!\cdot G(n+1)$.  See [Barnes G function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) for [more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed form expression, but we can evaluate its asymptotics by first taking its logarithm, and then employing [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).